# Visual Studio 2013 installation issue

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to install Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 on a Windows 2008 Server R2 SP1 with the .iso file and i'm facing some trouble. Here is what happen when i'm trying to install it :

[Visual Studio Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhz9z.png)

Here is the french problem, if you translate it, it says :

(X) Linguistic ressources Tools générations - x86 
Incorrect function

Thanks for your help

Comment: That is just the default message for error 1.  It of course doesn't tell you what "error 1" really means and what caused it.  You'll have to dig through the install .log files to have a shot at it.

Answer (score 0):

I actually find the answer, i mounted the .iso and i was launching it from the disk. I just had to copy every file on the desktop, launch it and it worked.